Noisy radiators when heating comes on
I live in a flat with a communal heating system. I've never had a problem before but now the weather has gotten colder the system has come on. It runs from 6:30am to 11:15pm.
For the past few days every morning at 6:30 I am awoken by what sounds like water running through the pipes and radiators in flat and a clicking sound. It sounds louder in the living room which is the first room the heating passes through. It seems to stop and go silent after 30 mins to an hour and doesn't return till the next morning. Even if the radiators are turned down.
I have no idea what the cause is. I have tried bleeding the radiators but no air comes through, only water. All radiators when turned on get fully hot so I don't think that's the problem.
All radiators are fitted with Drayton TRV4's but pretty sure they are wearing out and have some new ones arriving tomorrow. Would that solve the problem or could it be something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Have you tried bleeding the system? I would do that before paying for new valves...

Clicking may be thermal expansion and contraction of the pipes supplying the radiators. Depending on how they are supported,  friction against the supports may hold them back for a little while then let them move producing a click, with this repeating until they stabilize at a new temperature and size. The same thing can happen as they cool and contract, of course.
If you can find the place where this sticking occurs, you can try to do something about it, but sometimes it's sufficiently buried in the house"s structure that the work needed to cure it may be excessive.
Remember the standard advice for odd house sounds: unless they mean actual damage is occurring, sometimes the best thing to do is learn to ignore them. The human hearing system is very good at filtering out sounds that it does not consider threatening or interesting, given a chance to learn them. I have a similar click in my hot water pipes, which I have stopped hearing unless I am actively listening for it, just as I normally don't notice that my floors squeak. There is a distinct thump when my boiler ignites, which I found very loud initially but now literally have not heard in a decade, though I'm sure it's still there.
If I was trying to set up a home recording studio, all of this would matter much more. But even then, the easiest fix would be to turn off the heating system while I am recording, rather than renovating the building.
Summary: if it really bothers you, it can be fixed, but you will have to find exactly where the sound is coming from to determine how it is being produced and what needs to be done to silence it. And only you can decide whether it is worth the effort. If it isn't doing harm, you may want to just ignore it.
